# ошибка в библиотеке

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram, библиотека

как решить данную проблему?

```
Goodbye!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 320, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
  File "C:\Users\Артем\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 372, in _startup_polling
    await self._welcome()
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 361, in _welcome
    user = await self.dispatcher.bot.me
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 30, in me
    setattr(self, '_me', await self.get_me())
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 233, in get_me
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 121, in check_result
    exceptions.Unauthorized.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Артем\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.Unauthorized: Unauthorized

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Токен корректный указан?

Comment: код дай хоть какойто

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в вашем токене! Проверьте токен/создайте новый через @BotFather